# What file operations are available with ssh2:// in PHP

Tags: php, file-io, sftp, glob

I'm rewriting a function that processed and sorted files on the local server with one that can do so on a remote server reached through an ssh connection.

The existing system uses the pecl ssh2 library to grab specific files such like:

```
if ($stream = @fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/$filename", "r")) {
//do stuff...
}
```

But I don't know the filename already. I hade this working locally using

```
$file_path =  ABSOLUTE_PATH . UPLOAD_URL . $importfolder . '/';
$file = '*.xml';
$files = glob($file_path.$file);
```

I can't get glob() working through the ssh server

```
$files = glob("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/*.xml");
```

(always comes back blank despite a number of xml files in the directory (the sftp connection is to a single directory).

how can I acheive this? Can I use functions like glob() here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simply use the [ssh2 functions](http://php.net/ssh2)...

ie.

```
$session = ssh2_connect('some.server', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($session, 'username', 'password');
$stream = ssh2_exec($session, 'ls -la /some/path');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
echo "list of files: " . stream_get_contents($stream);
```

Comment: Wasn't able to see any that do not require a literal filepath be passed

Comment: you can execute shell commands to find your files, like `ls` or `find | grep` etc. updated the answer...

Comment: Unfortunately looks like I'm not cleared for that: *"Unable to request command execution on remote host"*

Comment: I can do regular sftp moving functions and am authenticated, but no commandline clearance

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

print_r($sftp->nlist()); // == $sftp->nlist('.')
print_r($sftp->rawlist()); // == $sftp->rawlist('.')
?>
```

(uses [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/))