# php sftp get files starting with a prefix

Tags: php, file, ssh, sftp

I would like to list all the files starting with a prefix from a directory in an other server

I am connected to an other server using ssh2_connect function, the connection is going well and i am able to fetch all files but i am not sure how to fetch only the required files from the directory.

For Eg: say i need files starting with TP00*.*
For some reason the glob() is not working with sftp.

my code is as follows

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
$sftp_fd = intval($sftp);

$handle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://$sftp_fd/path/to/directory");
echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
echo "Entries:\n";
while (false != ($entry = readdir($handle))){
    echo "$entry\n";
}
```

Any help is appriciated!

Additional Info : 
The file name which i gave is just an example. It's not always starting with TP00. I need to match it dynamically which depends on random generated IDS say TP00, W0D0, YAL0 and so on (no specific pattern but i can get the prefix).

What i tried with glob() is as follows

```
$files = glob("ssh2.sftp://$sftp_fd/path/to/directory/TP00*.*");
```

This did not return any files. And no error is thrown. So am not sure why its not working.

What am trying to do is get array of matched files without iterating through the entire files because the folder contains too many files.

Comment: What stops you by using a client side/php filter for the pattern check ?

Comment: I dont know how to do it...

Comment: There is no glob() in the code you've shown us. What does "not working" mean? It gives an error? doesn't find the data? Sulks in the corner?

Comment: If the solution fixxed your Problem pleas select it as solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex Expressions for that :
`TP00.*?\..*?$`

Example of usage :

```
if (preg_match('/TP00.*?\..*?$/i', $entry)){
    // $entry is in the right format
}
```

Another possible solution can be found here as an answer [What file operations are available with ssh2:// in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901040/what-file-operations-are-available-with-ssh2-in-php)